# Finding the ID associated to the maximum in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

Let's say I have data such as:

```
ID_A    ID_B    ID_C    NUM_1
123     124     0       72
123     124     1       90
123     124     1       80
```

I would like to add two columns to my data. The first would pick out the maximum of NUM_1 (grouped by ID_A, ID_B, ID_C), and the second would pick out ID_C corresponding to the maximum of NUM_1.

For this data, the answer would be

```
ID_A    ID_B    ID_C    NUM_1   MAX_1   MAX_ID
123     124     0       72      72      0
123     124     1       90      90      1
123     124     1       80      90      1
```

Using something like

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.TEST1 AS 
SELECT t1.ID_A, 
      t1.ID_B, 
      t1.ID_C, 
      t1.NUM_1,
      /* Max_1 */
        (MAX(t1.NUM_1)) FORMAT=13.2 AS MAX_1

  FROM WORK.TEST t1
  GROUP BY t1.ID_A, 
           t1.ID_B, 
           t1.ID_C 
  HAVING MAX(t1.NUM_1)
  ORDER BY t1.ID_A, 
           t1.ID_B, 
           t1.ID_C, 
           t1.NUM_1;
QUIT;
```

I am able to get the maximum, repeated in the desired rows, but it does not get me the MAX_ID, repeated in the desired rows that I want.

I am new to SAS, but I have tried for awhile to get this and I apologize if this is covered elsewhere.

I am using SAS EG by the way, so if you know how to do this using data steps I am amenable to that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is SQL code; you might have more luck asking it as an SQL question.

Comment: I added a sql tag. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There's a few extra commas in the code pasted above, and the query should end with a semicolon.  Unfortunately I can't fix it because it wouldn't meed stackoverflow's 6-character edit minimum.

Answer (score 3):

In SAS, you can use the `having` clause like so:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table tallest as
  select name, height
  from sashelp.class
  having height = max(height)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that this will give the maximum value. Does this also give the ID associated to that specific maximum?

Comment: @Autoleech Name is the id variable in the example query Robert posts.  This is taking advantage of SAS's willingness to remerge the summarization with the main table (in this case, the `max(height)`).   This wouldn't work in most flavors of SQL without doing the join by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Another SAS option is to use `PROC MEANS` with `idgroup`.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class noprint;
var height;
output out=tallest  idgroup(max(height) out (name height)=);
run;
```

That puts out the maximum value of height with any other values you want that go along with it (in this case, name, which is effectively an id variable).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

The line below works on your example data.  It might need to be tweaked if there are special cases in your full data.  It would go after the clause defining `MAX_1`.

```
(select distinct t2.ID_C from test as t2 where t1.NUM_1 = t2.NUM_1) as MAX_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code is giving me the error "Subquery evaluated to more than one row".

Comment: This probably means you have a tie for the highest NUM_1 in some ID group.